# Неправильный вывод даты MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Хочу вывести с 01.09.2018, а он выводит с 2017. Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас происходлит вот что.

Вы берете дату. Преобразуете её к строке. Используя свой собственный формат, в котром число, потом месяц, потом год.

Потом вы начинаете сравнивать строки. Строки - по умолчанию - сортируются лексикографически. То есть, "как в словаре". Это и приводит к ошибке: дата начинает при сортировке быть более значимой, чем год.

Попробуйте в выражении where использовать другой формат даты (и не преобразовывать дату к строке):

```
    op.dt >= '2018-09-01'
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Сработало